# Customise actual/expected "Value of" string in Google Test failure output messages

Tags: c++, googletest

I have the following output from a [Google Test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) unit test:

```
UnitTests.cc:56: Failure
Value of: LineSegment2i(Vector2i(-10,0), Vector2i(-10,10)).toLine()
  Actual: 24-byte object <00-00 00-00 00-00 24-C0 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00 2F-2B FF-7F 00-00>
Expected: Line(10, 3.14159265358979323846)
Which is: 24-byte object <00-00 00-00 00-00 24-40 18-2D 44-54 FB-21 09-40 00-00 64-00 00-00 00-00>
[  FAILED  ] LineSegmentTests.toLine (1 ms)
```

That hexadecimal output string isn't very useful. Is there something I can add to the `Line` class (for which an equality test is failing) to provide more helpful errors in such cases?

The class in question has overridden the `<<` operator as a member function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream) const
{
  return stream << "Line (radius=" << d_radius << " theta=" << d_theta << ")";
}
```

<strike>You can see that this works for the 'Expected' line, but not the 'Actual' line.</strike> This statement is untrue — the test shown comes from the parameter of the `TEST` macro.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to print custom types you could "teach" Google Test how to print your custom types which as described in the section [Teaching Google Test How to Print Your Values](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values).

Answer (score 12):

The header in the `gtest-printers.h` source file provides an answer:

> This file implements a universal value printer that can print a value of any type T:
>
> void ::testing::internal::UniversalPrinter::Print(value, ostream_ptr);
>
> A user can teach this function how to print a class type T by defining either operator<<() or PrintTo() in the namespace that defines T.  More specifically, the FIRST defined function in the following list will be used (assuming T is defined in namespace foo):
>
> 1. foo::PrintTo(const T&, ostream*)
> 2. operator<<(ostream&, const T&) defined in either foo or the global namespace.
>
> If none of the above is defined, it will print the debug string of the value if it is a protocol buffer, or print the raw bytes in the value otherwise.

So it looks like the operator override needs to be a non-member function.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Line const& line)
{
  return stream << "Line (radius=" << line.radius() << " theta=" << line.theta() << ")";
}
```

Comment: Is there something more needed if my type is a class template?  I have `operator<<` defined in the namespace.  If I have `EXPECT_EQ(v1, v2) << v1 << ' ' << v2;`, the expected and actual values print in the "xx-byte object" format but my addendum successfully invokes my custom printer.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it may better to provide a `PrintTo()` function instead of a stream operator. E.g. if you want to customize how a container (having `begin()`/`end()`) is printed, the existing internal operators of Google Test will currently have priority over custom operators. In that case your operator will not work but a `PrintTo()` function will. Definition looks like this:

```
void PrintTo(const Range& range, ::std::ostream* os)
{
   *os << range;
}
```

Also see here: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/3458