# GTest change output of failure

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock

I have written a Parameterized Gtest using a struct I made as the parameter value. When the test fails it writes a byte object of the struct like so:

```
[  FAILED  ] RulesNoProcessing/StressTest.MainTest/2, where GetParam() = 
             40-byte object <01-12 00-00 02-00 00-00 F4-01 00-00 ...>.
```

Is there anyway way that I can customize the output? I know that there is predicate formats for assertions but I need to do something similar with the actual outcome of the test. If anyone can I help I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have seen this: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#teaching-google-test-how-to-print-your-values ?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam Yes I had seen that but I can't see how I can get that to edit the summary test result output? Don't suppose you would know how?

Comment: Found the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191004/customise-actual-expected-value-of-string-in-google-test-failure-output-messag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customise actual/expected "Value of" string in Google Test failure output messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191004/customise-actual-expected-value-of-string-in-google-test-failure-output-messag)

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the "operator <<", for example

```
struct Row
{
  int window;
  int osmap;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Row& bar) {
  return os << "w = " << bar.window << ", opsmap= " << bar.osmap;  // whatever needed to print
  }
};
```

Look this for more info https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values

Comment: The link is broken.